# Validating forms from DIFFERENT pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am curious as to how one would rewrite a validation block that encompasses multiple forms from different pages?

I currently have this code, but I know that this only validates forms on the same page.

```
$('form').each(function () {
    $(this).validate( {
        rules: {
        }
    });
});
```

I am currently using this block in an external js file to try to validate multiple forms. However, I have 5 pages - each with one form - and this validate() block only works on the first form on the first page. I do not want to write validation blocks for each form, so how can I re-write this block to accommodate the forms from different pages? Is it even possible?

Comment: what plugin was used?

Comment: The jQuery validation plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a common css class on each form and create common js file and include it on each page.

```
$("form[class='validate']").each({
   $(this).validate({
     // your roles..
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would do it, take a look.

```js
$("form[class='validate']").each({
var rules = {};
var method = $(this).attr("vMethod");

console.log("validating");
switch(vMethod)
{
 case "roles":
  rules = {rules:...} // your library 
  break;
  
 case "user":
  rules = {rules:...} // your library 
  break;

}
$(this).validate(rules);
});
```

```html
<form class="validate" vMethod="roles"></form>

<form class="validate" vMethod="user"></form>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: The "cases" are definitely the names or ids of the forms, am I right?

Comment: No the cases is `vMethod` attribute, but yeh you could also say that its a form name. but think if you have two forms with the same validation methods on the same page then its better too use an attribute `vMethod` insetad of `name` or `id`.

Comment: Ah! Your explanation's helpful! I'm wondering would this work on forms that are not on the same page?

Comment: Yes it would but you have to make it a `function validate()` then trigger it after `forms` has been loaded or maybe at form `submit`. `$(document).ready` is a good place too.

Comment: Wait what do you mean not on the same page? this will get all forms that exist in the current page. if you have two tabs then no :)

Comment: I meant forms from different pages under the same website.

Comment: Test it out, you have already market @Daniel Smith as answer so if hes code work then mine should too